# MVC 5 How do I make another type of account register in a different table in the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

So by the MVC 5 template, when you register for a new account, it is being stored in the AspNetUsers table in the database. I made another table called AspNetCompanies which is basically a clone of AspNetUsers (for now) and I made another .cshtml in the View folder and a "RegisterCompanyViewModel" in the AccountViewModels.cs Controller.
What I wanna do is when I click on register after all the forms are filled, it should create a new company account in AspNetCompanies, and how do I do this? I tried finding where the binding to my database's table is but couldn't find it.

I guess in short what I'm trying to do is have two types of accounts and be able to use the same login page for both of them.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Well I want to have two types of accounts, with different fields. I already have two roles for using [Authorize] for companies/users but I cannot figure out where the register method is connected to the AspNetUsers table?

Comment: Why not just use `AspNetUsers` and extend it with the extra fields from `AspNetCompanies` and a `UserType` flag? Your application can then determine what type of `ViewModel` the user will be depending on the `UserType` and copy the necessary fields from the model into the `ViewModel` that will be displayed.

Comment: I think I tried to do something similar but failed? Can you please elaborate? Wouldn't it be confusing to have two types of users thrown into the same table? I guess if I need just one I can run a query.

Comment: When I make the username field in the DB "allows nulls" and I leave it blank when trying to register, it wont work?